# Form submit runs JavaScript that "GET" XML and fills out webpage checkboxes via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to input an email address in to a form

```
 <div class="login_div">
      <h2>Login with Email Address for Subscriptions</h2>
          <label for="email_address">Email Address</label> 
          <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="required email" />
          <br/>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>

         <input 
            type="submit" 
            value="Login"  
            class="btnlogin get_started nothidden"
            onclick="return setCurrentSubs()"/>

  </div>
```

on submit the simple form should run a script via js that appends the email address onto the xml data that is received from the server. I am able to get the xml feed if I put the action in the form but I cannot get the xml into the subsequent page where the check boxes are for the xml feed.

my biggest problem is that I need to add a place for the email address in the js script right now I have

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fundinvestor/ETsubscriberListEmail",     
        dataType: "xml",
        setData: 
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        },
        success: setCurrentSubs
});
```

I am not sure what to add so the email address is appended onto script. I tried this

```
type : "GET",
        url : "/fundinvestor/ETsubscriberListEmail",        
        dataType : "xml",
        data:({
            email : $('#email').val(),
    }),
```

but not sure if this is right.

Comment: Why don't you think it is right?

Comment: the xml comes back empty

Comment: So where is the server code? Where are you reading the email address, where are you setting the XML? Are you looking for a GET parameter or a POST on the server?

Comment: @epascarllo When the url is example: http://www.company.com/fundinvestor/ETsubscriberListEmail?email=emailname I can get the proper xml list. this is used with a GET parameter since I am trying to pull information from the server and post it to a webpage.

Comment: `data: {email: "foo@example.com"}`  Should set the querystring. Look at the request in the web developer console and see if you see the value.

Comment: ok, that works when I pre fill the email but I need the input from the email to be appended to the "GET". How would I enter in that.

Comment: it should be appended to the querystring...

Comment: I changed data:({email : $('#email').val(),}), to data:{email : "foo@example.com"}, and it worked just fin appending the email on to the url. But I need to attach the email value from the form into the data parameter. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe we need to see more of your code, show the full javascript code